# How to send mail to the client after submitting Google Form?

Tags: google-forms, notifications

I create a Google Form. I want to mail my client when he submit the form. Now, I am doing this using form notification add-ons. But, problem is, I can't send any text that refer to a link. I use `<a href="link">name</a>` but not works.

How can I do this?